# Azure function upload file to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I tried to use Azure function to upload file to Azure Blob. From my Angular front end, I uploaded the file using input to get the HTML 5 File object

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload', file);

const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' });

const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', url-to-my-azure-function, formData, { headers: headers});
return this.http.request(req);
```

When the Azure function was trigger, I tried to use

```
blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream("mycontainer", "myfilename", req.body, req.body.length, function(error, result) {...});
```

to create the blob, but it gives me exception

```
Exception: TypeError: stream.pause is not a function
```

When I used the output binding directly to create the blob, it is working. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To upload file using `input` tag in HTML page, here is a demo for your reference:

```
var blobUri = 'https://' + 'STORAGE_ACCOUNT' + '.blob.core.windows.net';
var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, 'SAS_TOKEN');

// If one file has been selected in the HTML file input element
var file = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0];

var customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512;
blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;

var finishedOrError = false;
var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('containerName', 
file.name, file, {blockSize : customBlockSize}, function(error, result, response) {
    finishedOrError = true;
    if (error) {
        // Upload blob failed
    } else {
        // Upload successfully
    }
});
```

For more information, we can refer to: [Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library Sample for Blob Operations](https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html)

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I looked at the example. But my problem is a bit different. I don't use the createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile directly when the File is there. Instead, I want to send the File object to another file management service (Azure function) through HTTP and that service intends to call  createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile to upload the file to Azure blob. But when I try HttpRequest('PUT', url-to-my-azure-function, file, { headers: headers}); the data in the request body seems not the File object anymore. So I can't use createBlockBlobFromBroswerFile. Tried to use stream, but got exception.